# Dalvik Virtual Machine gives error “VFY: invoke type does not match method type of…” when running pre-compiled javascript by Mozilla Rhino

Tags: android

Application uses Mozilla Rhino Version 1.7R4 to pre-compile the javascript file and to execute it at runtime. While executing it at runtime on DVM, it gives below error while loading pre-compiled javascript class file:

```
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/dalvikvm(12965): VFY: invoke type does not match method type of Lcom/test/converted/script;._c_script_0_literal1
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/dalvikvm(12965): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at 0x000c
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/dalvikvm(12965): VFY:  rejected Lcom/test/converted/script;._c_script_0 (Lcom/test/converted/script;Lorg/mozilla/javascript/Context;Lorg/mozilla/javascript/Scriptable;Lorg/mozilla/javascript/Scriptable;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/dalvikvm(12965): Verifier rejected class Lcom/test/converted/script;
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.converted.script
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at com.notworkingrhino.AppImpl.populateScopeFromCompiledScriptClass(AppImpl.java:36)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at com.notworkingrhino.AppImpl.loadScripts(AppImpl.java:25)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at com.notworkingrhino.AppImpl.onCreate(AppImpl.java:17)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:981)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5005)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/test/converted/script
12-23 16:34:10.560: W/System.err(12965):    ... 18 more
```

While investigating more on problem, I found that "_c_script_0_literal1" method creates a problem on DVM which only gets generated when any Object Literal have more than 10 properties inside it in a javascript. If Object Literal has 10 or less than 10 properties then the above method is not generated in a class file and it works fine.

Note that the same class file having “_c_script_0_literal1” method works fine on JVM but only creates problem on DVM.

For reference, Please refer following two jars which has compiled javascript class files generated by Mozilla Rhino:

1. [NotWorkingRhinoScripts.jar](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=4754CC4A7DB7A810!109): Containing class file of following javascript

   var Codes = {
           ONE : 1,
           TWO : 2,
           THREE : 3,
           FOUR : 4,
           FIVE : 5,
           SIX : 6,
           SEVEN : 7,
           EIGHT : 8,
           NINE : 9,
           TEN : 10,
           ELEVEN : 11
       };
2. [WorkingRhinoScripts.jar](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=4754CC4A7DB7A810!108): Containing class file of following javascript

   var Codes = {
               ONE : 1,
               TWO : 2,
               THREE : 3,
               FOUR : 4,
               FIVE : 5,
               SIX : 6,
               SEVEN : 7,
               EIGHT : 8,
               NINE : 9,
               TEN : 10
           };

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. What is your question? You already filed an issue for this (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64043).

Comment: The question is why DVM is giving such error while running this class file generated from javascript file, while it's working fine on JVM.